# Слово "розстрибуватися" та похідні

Tags: вибір-слова

Мене цікавить наскільки слово "[розстрибуватися](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozstrybatysja)" властиве українській мові в значенні процесу стрибання(це важливо - це динамічний процес), котрий стає все більш та більш інтенсивним, що вочевидь не є значенням цього слова у СУМ-11, і чи можна його вживати?
Також: чи існує похідне слово "розстрибування"? Якщо немає - які є альтернативи? Я займаюся перекладом і є ігровий термін "bunnyhopping", який я хотів би саме так перекласти і жодного адекватного замінника/відповідника цьому слову в українській не можу знайти.

**UPD:** Якщо слово "розстрибування" існує та є легітимним - "bunnyhopping" самe так буде і має перекладатися. Питання не про переклад, а про легітимність слова "розстрибування" і про наявність можливих синонімів процесу стрибання, котрий стає все більш та більш інтенсивним.

Comment: Якщо це запитання про переклад, то вкажіть контекст і приблизний переклад своїми словами. Якщо ж, натомість, запитання про усталеність українського слова «розстрибування», то незрозуміло, яким чином іноземне слово допоможе відповісти на це запитання.

Comment: @bytebuster Це питання про усталеність. `Також: чи існує похідне слово "розстрибування"?` "bunnyhoping"  - це слово, яке я хочу перекласти як "розстрибування. Допомогу по перекладу я ніде не просив.

Comment: прибрав теґ [tag:from-english] згідно коментаря автора запитання.

Comment: А можете пояснити, що мається на увазі під «bunnyhopping»?

Comment: @Sasha 

Bunny hopping is a video game technique used in first-person shooter 
(FPS) games in which the player continually runs and jumps, often while 
firing a weapon. Bunny hopping usually serves one of two purposes:  
  - Avoiding Attacks: Bunny hopping can throw off opponents' aim and give the hopper an opportunity to attack.
  - Gaining Speed: Bunny hopping can increase the speed at which players move, allowing them to close the distance when attacking opponents.

Російською термін називається "Распрыжка".

Comment: То ви перекладаєте з англійської чи російської?

Comment: Взагалі, слово це спеціалізоване, навіть жаргонне. Раджу не намагатись вгадати, як воно має бути, а спитати україномовних геймерів, який термін вони використовують.

Comment: @Kreiri Я навів приклад перекладу англійського слова на російську, який є правильним. Перекладу на українську я не знаю і я не зміг знайти жодного перекладу цього виразу українською, тому проводжу паралель із російським правильним перекладом слова, проте я не знаю чи таке слово існує в українській мові і чи це не калькування. Геймери, імовірно, використовують саме слово "розстрибування", проте в мене немає жодного не суб'єктивного перекладу цього слова. Напевно, я усе-таки буду використовувати слово "розстрибування", оскільки ніхто не заперечив тут існування цього слова.

Comment: Ви так і до "дозволу екрану" доперекладаєтеся.

Comment: "Ніхто тут не заперечив", тому що bunnyhopping як термін в комп'ютерних іграх - це спеціалізований термін сфери комп'ютерних ігор, і якраз знавців в цій сфері тут не знайшлося.  Зверніться до знавців цієї сфери, не перекладайте наївно "в лоб" російський відповідник.

Comment: Проблема в тому, як я зазначив раніше, усталеного перекладу цього слова немає НІДЕ. Я впевнений на 200%, що "знавці" запропонують такий самий переклад(якщо вони знають взагалі що це таке. Я особисто не знаю людей з України, котрі спілкуються українською та котрі ставили рекорди в спідранах ігр, де така техніка є дуже популярною) і це не змінить факт того, що це суб'єктивна думка. Моє ж питання полягає не в тому чи я правильно переклав. Якщо слово існує - переклад правильний або близький до правильного. До дозволу екрана не доперекладаюсь, в мене fluent english і перекладаю я не одне слово.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Питання не про переклад, а про легітимність слова "розстрибування", – неправильний, як на мене, підхід до формулювання й вирішення проблеми, адже в такий спосіб відбувається зміщення акцентів. Замість дослідити термін і вибрати якнайкращий відповідник для нього, просто підшукуються аргументи, щоб виправдати вже ухвалене рішення: взяти переклад із російського перекладу.

Основні значення, на яких варто зосередитися: рухатися дуже швидко, стрибаючи та стріляючи водночас; виконати швидку послідовність стрибків; скажено стрибати навколо під час стрілянини ([брала звідси](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bunny-hopping)). Непросто добрати відповідник, що охоплював би одним словом і стрибки, і біг, і стрілянину, оскільки його просто не існує (була б рада помилитися і виявити, що таке слово десь є). Російське "распрыжка" тільки частково вирішує це завдання, оскільки зосереджується на одній складовій – стрибанні. І якщо вже брати цей момент за стрижневий та будувати термін, базуючись на ньому, то є слово "плигати", що означає переміщуватися стрибками, та "плигання" – дія за значенням плигати. Обидва зафіксовані у словниках, тож питань щодо нормативності виникати не мало б.

Щодо розстрибування, якщо вже дуже хочеться це слово. Префікс *роз-* надає лексичного значення *[руху ізсередини назовні, відокремлювання](http://ena.lp.edu.ua:8080/bitstream/ntb/11881/1/2.pdf)*. Так утворюються дієслова розливати, розхлюпувати, розбігатися, розшаровувати(ся), розкидати тощо. До багатьох із них зафіксовані відповідні іменники: розшарування, розшифрування, розкидання. Наступне уже без дослідження джерел, а суто моя думка: припускаю, що розстрибування також утворюється за таким принципом. Тільки ще раз: тут я не досліджувала детально й не можу сказати, наскільки це нормативно, чи можна на підставі цих прикладів робити такий висновок.

Comment: Мені здається, що це поки найкращий варіант, все одно ідеального перекладу не досягти, як цього не хотілося б.

Answer (score 1):

В СУМі є слово "[розстрибатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozstrybatysja)", але для того, щоб сказати наскільки точно воно передає значення слова "розстрибуватися" потрібно знати значення останнього. Хоч мені здається, що "розстрибуватися" - це недоконана форма дієслова "розстрибатися". А от на рахунок слова "розстрибування" я не впевнений, принаймі його в СУМі немає.

Наскільки я зрозумів, то "bunnyhopping" - це спосіб за допомогою якою гравець розганяє свого персонажа. Тобто він скаче і його швикість збільшується. Мені здається, що ще коли я тільки пішов в школу вийшла така гра Quake 3 і там цей прийом досить часто використовували (якщо комусь цікаво, то можна подивитися відео на [Ютубі](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX16AiApAR8), щоб краще розуміти про що йдеться). Тому я вирішив пошукати на різних геймерських порталах інформацію про цей прийом.

На жаль, тут я помилився і мої пошуки нічого не дали. Але я згадав, що тоді ж була популярна гра [CS 1.6](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-Strike#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8), і як тільки я зайшов на Вікіпедію, то в розділі "Додаткові типи карт" знайшов:

> bh, bhop — Bunny Hopping (Кролячі стрибання). Карти для тренування
>   стрибків.

І так, слово "стрибання" справді є в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/strybannja).

А ще ви знали, що є такий [велосипедний трюк](http://factosvit.com.ua/sposoby-vykonannya-elementiv-trialu/bannihop-abo-zayachyj-strybok-fazy-strybka/), який називається "БанніХоп" або "Заячий стрибок"? Він також походить від англійського "bunnyhop".

Comment: От і я його не знайшов, проте мені здається, що таке слово має бути, оскільки є дієслово.

Comment: @improbable, А чим вам не підходить варіант "Кролячі стрибання"?

Comment: Спільнота не користується таким терміном. Воно не інтуїтивне і погано передає сутність слова-процесу. Більшість далеко не відразу зрозуміє, що воно означає.